# Codeigniter: Ion auth reset password

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am using the Ion auth library with codeigniter and have created a login, register, remember me and forgot password features (so far).

For the forgot password feature, the user types in their email address, they are then sent an email with a link to reset the password.

A page opens with them to type in the new password and confirmation password and when i click submit i get this error in my php log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Auth::_valid_csrf_nonce() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Auth/application/controllers/auth.php on line 273
```

I have not changed anything when downloading this library so wondering where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Here is my code to support this:

Auth Controller:

```
function _get_csrf_nonce()
    {
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $key = random_string('alnum', 8);
        $value = random_string('alnum', 20);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfkey', $key);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfvalue', $value);

        return array($key => $value);
    } 

    //reset password - final step for forgotten password
    public function reset_password($code = NULL)
    {
        if (!$code)
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $user = $this->ion_auth->forgotten_password_check($code);

        if ($user)
        {
            //if the code is valid then display the password reset form

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('new', 'New Password', 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[new_confirm]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_confirm', 'Confirm New Password', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
            {
                //display the form

                //set the flash data error message if there is one
                $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

                $this->data['min_password_length'] = $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth');
                $this->data['new_password'] = array(
                    'name' => 'new',
                    'id'   => 'new',
                'type' => 'password',
                    'pattern' => '^.{'.$this->data['min_password_length'].'}.*$'
                );
                $this->data['new_password_confirm'] = array(
                    'name' => 'new_confirm',
                    'id'   => 'new_confirm',
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'pattern' => '^.{'.$this->data['min_password_length'].'}.*$'
                );
                $this->data['user_id'] = array(
                    'name'  => 'user_id',
                    'id'    => 'user_id',
                    'type'  => 'hidden',
                    'value' => $user->id
                );
                $this->data['csrf'] = $this->_get_csrf_nonce();
                $this->data['code'] = $code;

                //render
                $this->_render_page('reset_password', $this->data);
            }
            else
            {
                // do we have a valid request?
                if ($this->_valid_csrf_nonce() === FALSE || $user->id != $this->input->post('user_id'))
                {

                    //something fishy might be up
                    $this->ion_auth->clear_forgotten_password_code($code);

                    show_error('This form post did not pass our security checks.');

                }else{
                    // finally change the password
                    $identity = $user->{$this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth')};

                    $change = $this->ion_auth->reset_password($identity, $this->input->post('new'));

                    if ($change)
                    {
                        //if the password was successfully changed
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                        $this->logout();
                    }else{
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                        redirect('reset_password/' . $code, 'refresh');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if the code is invalid then send them back to the forgot password page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect("forgot_password", 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Forgotten password model function:

```
/**
     * Forgotten Password Complete
     *
     * @return string
     * @author Mathew
     **/
    public function forgotten_password_complete($code, $salt=FALSE)
    {
        $this->trigger_events('pre_forgotten_password_complete');

        if (empty($code))
        {
            $this->trigger_events(array('post_forgotten_password_complete', 'post_forgotten_password_complete_unsuccessful'));
            return FALSE;
        }

        $profile = $this->where('forgotten_password_code', $code)->users()->row(); //pass the code to profile

        if ($profile) {

            if ($this->config->item('forgot_password_expiration', 'ion_auth') > 0) {
                //Make sure it isn't expired
                $expiration = $this->config->item('forgot_password_expiration', 'ion_auth');
                if (time() - $profile->forgotten_password_time > $expiration) {
                    //it has expired
                    $this->set_error('forgot_password_expired');
                    $this->trigger_events(array('post_forgotten_password_complete', 'post_forgotten_password_complete_unsuccessful'));
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            $password = $this->salt();

            $data = array(
                'password'                => $this->hash_password($password, $salt),
                'forgotten_password_code' => NULL,
                'active'                  => 1,
             );

            $this->db->update($this->tables['users'], $data, array('forgotten_password_code' => $code));

            $this->trigger_events(array('post_forgotten_password_complete', 'post_forgotten_password_complete_successful'));
            return $password;
        }

        $this->trigger_events(array('post_forgotten_password_complete', 'post_forgotten_password_complete_unsuccessful'));
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Reset Password View:

```
<div id="infoMessage"><?php echo $message;?></div>

<?php echo form_open('auth/reset_password/' . $code);?>

    <p>
        New Password (at least <?php echo $min_password_length;?> characters long): <br />
        <?php echo form_input($new_password);?>
    </p>

    <p>
        Confirm New Password: <br />
        <?php echo form_input($new_password_confirm);?>
    </p>

    <?php echo form_input($user_id);?>
    <?php echo form_hidden($csrf); ?>

    <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Change');?></p>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have this method in your auth file?

```
function _valid_csrf_nonce()
{
    if ($this->input->post($this->session->flashdata('csrfkey')) !== FALSE && $this->input->post($this->session->flashdata('csrfkey')) == $this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue')) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

if not then add it.